# Why is the Bootstrap button tooltip feature deleting my button titles from the HTML?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1. I have a set of buttons on my page, with Bootstrap tooltips:

```
<button id="btnDrawMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Draw Polygon'><i class="fas fa-draw-polygon"></i></button>
<button id="btnSnapToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Toggle Snapping'><i class="fas fa-vector-square" id="btnSnapToggleSymbol"></i></button>
<button id="btnModifyMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Modify Zone'><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
<button id="btnEraseMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Delete Zone'><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></button> 
<button id="btnFinish" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Finish & Save'><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
```

When I load the page in Edge, it throws issues saying that my buttons have empty `title` attributes. When I inspect the code, my `title` attributes have all been cleared, with the titles moved into new `data-original-title` attributes:

```
<button id="btnDrawMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Draw Polygon">
<button id="btnSnapToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Toggle Snapping">
<button id="btnModifyMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Modify Zone">
<button id="btnEraseMode" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete Zone">
<button id="btnFinish" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Finish &amp; Save">
```

Obviously this doesn't impact the user experience at all, but Edge is complaining and I want to stop that from happening. Is this being caused by Bootstrap? How do I fix this?